# Get the contents of div items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the data in a within the description inside the product items. I'm trying to do this with jquery.

```js
$(".dl-view-item").click(function() {
  var sku = $(this).find(".product.description").find.data("sku");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dl-view-item">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="description" data-sku="sample-data">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the data in data-sku

Comment: ".product.description" finds elements with both ".product" and ".description". Put a space or `>` to find descendants or immediate children. Also, no reason for `.find.data` -- just `.data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```js
$(".dl-view-item").click(function() {
  var sku = $(this).find(".product.description");
  console.log(sku)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dl-view-item">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="description" data-sku="sample-data"> 
            Lorem ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(".dl-view-item").click(function () {
        
         var sku = $(".dl-view-item").find("div.description").attr("data-sku");
console.log(sku);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dl-view-item"> Click Me!
  <div class="product">
    <div class="description" data-sku="sample-data">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not query for an ID at the top level. This should be a class that you query relevant to the clicked item.

Comment: hope it'll help. @Ömer Özdemir

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between your selector classes.

> `.product.description`

Alternatively, instead of simply supplying a space here, you could use a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) since the description is an immediate child of the the product container. If this is not the case, you can remove the `>` in the selector.

> `.product > .description`

```js
$('.dl-view-item').click(function() {
  var sku = $(this).find('.product > .description').data('sku');
  console.log(sku);
});
```

```css
.dl-view-item {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dl-view-item">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="description" data-sku="sample-data">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

By the way, you can do this without jQuery.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dl-view-item').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let sku = e.target.querySelector('.product > .description').dataset.sku;
    console.log(sku);
  })
});
```

```css
.dl-view-item {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dl-view-item">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="description" data-sku="sample-data">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".dl-view-item").click(function () {
      var sku = $(this).find("div.description").data("sku");
      $(this).find("div.description").text(sku);
   });
});
```